# do not show single quotes for a variable shell script

Tags: shell, echo

I have a variable `userName="testUser"` which goes into another string called Data. 
I am currently not sure how to to get rid of the sing quotes. If I do not give the single quotes the userName will be taken as a string literal.

```
Data="<Resource  name="\"jdbc/datSource"\" auth="\"Container"\" \n factory="\"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"\" driverClassName=\"\oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver\"\ username=\"\'${userName}'\"\ />"
```

Eventually what I am getting is

```
name="jdbc/datSource" auth="Container" 
 factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" username="'testUser'" />
```

Just need to print `username="testUser"`

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use ES6 template literals (`${...}`) and for these to work, you need to use ES6 back ticks... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Please let me know if i am missing the point.

Comment: *If I do not give the single quotes the userName will be taken as a string literal.* What shell are you using? It works fine for me in `bash` without the single quotes.

Comment: I am using gitbash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is you are escaping the `$` character.
It will work if you remove the single quotes and the `\` before the first single quote one.

`Data="<Resource  name="\"jdbc/datSource"\" auth="\"Container"\" \n factory="\"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"\" driverClassName=\"\oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver\"\ username=\"${userName}\"\ />"`

Answer (score 0):

Your quoting would be much less unnecessarily complicated if you used outer single quotes, and only switched to double quotes around the specific string you wish to expand:

```
userName="Test User"
Data='
<Resource  name="jdbc/datSource" auth="Container"
           factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
           driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
           username="'"${userName}"'" />
'

echo "$Data"
```

...properly emits:

```
<Resource  name="jdbc/datSource" auth="Container"
           factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
           driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
           username="Test User" />
```

---

**However, you shouldn't ever do this.** Use real XML-aware tools (ie.
 [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html)) to generate or edit XML.

If you were using XMLStarlet, for example, you could run this:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -u '//Resource[@name='jdbc/datSource']/@username' \
  -v "$userName" \
  <in.xml >out.xml
```

...to change the `username` for the `Resource` with name `jdbc/datSource` in your existing document.